# How can we use a touch sensor to detect a specific object like a biometric fingerprint sensor?

Tags: arduino, proximity-sensor

I have an Arduino connected to a touch sensor which is placed below a piece of 4mm thick glass.

I can use touch to turn and send signal to the Arduino.  I'd like the sensor to only detect a specific object like a glass or cup. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can’t is the simple answer. Your body acts as an antenna and via capacitance your touch can be detected electronically. Apart from the actual weight,glass or cup does not provide the same signal. If the cup was metal, you could use an inductive technique to detect it. But it could not determine if it were a cup or a badge. A vision system would be the obvious solution methinks.

Comment: How about we add a certain material below the cup and make the touch sensor only detect a certain range of capacitance that only the material below the cup can provide